# How do I fetch related resources through Joosy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, joosy

I created a vanilla joosy rails app following the tutorial in https://github.com/coshx/techlunches/tree/fdb70ff65997f9

There are two resources on both the rails and joosy side:

```
# app/models/presenter.rb
class Presenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :github_username, :name, :twitter_username

  has_many :presentations
end

# app/models/presentation.rb
class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title

  belongs_to :presenter
end

# app/assets/javascripts/techlunches/resources/presentation.js.coffee
# (next line needed because this file is loaded before presenter.js.coffee)
#= require techlunches/resources/presenter
class @Presentation extends Joosy.Resource.REST
  @entity 'presentation'
  @map 'presenter', @Presenter

# app/assets/javascripts/techlunches/resources/presenter.js.coffee
class @Presenter extends Joosy.Resource.REST
  @entity 'presenter'
  @map 'presentations', @Presentation
```

When I visit the home page, the following lines work in the console:

```
>> Presentation.find(1)('presenter_id')
   1
>> Presenter.find(1)('name')
   Ben
```

However, this line does not work

```
>> Presentation.find(1)('presenter')
   undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, resources are asynchronous – they request data from backend. Therefore it should be `Presentation.find 1, (presentation) -> presentation('presenter')`.

The other thing to note is that such request will return you the raw JSON data. If you are after association instance, use `presentation.presenter`.

Comment: `Presentation.find(1, function(p) { console.dir(p('presenter')); });` also shows me `undefined` in this case, so I'm seeing the same results when I switch to asynchronous style.

Comment: @BenTaitelbaum what does your server respond with? Do you include `presenter` into JSON response at your controller/view?

Comment: I just included `presenter_id` in the JSON, assuming that Joosy would understand that convention. Do I need to explicitly include the associated resource? This might be an area for future optimization, but for now do you have a preference between rable, jbuilder, or something else?

Comment: Joosy always makes the only HTTP request per any Resource search. It tries to settle what server responds with. So it's a duty of server to inline all the required associations. `@map` is a sugar to ease `Object`s wrapping.

You don't actually even need that `@map` if you want to make subrequest – just call `find` twice for every object. But you should not. You can simply use `include` option of `to_json`. But I would recommend `jbuilder`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in https://github.com/coshx/techlunches/commit/6ca72152d3c0b6a, although I couldn't get it to work with `presentations.presenter('name')`

Comment: In the provided code you make ('presenter')('name'). `.presenter('name')` should work well. What do you get in `.presenter`?

Comment: `.presenter` is undefined for me.